# Jenkins build failing java.io.IOException: Cannot run program error=13, Permission denied

Tags: gradle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gradlew

I have a jenkins pipeline where i am trying to run a gradle test and it has a .sh file which the test needs to run. While running the test it fails at the step where it tries to run .sh file with the error
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./src/test/resource/TestFiles/myshell.sh": error=13, Permission denied

I have tried adding the command chmod +x in 2 ways but both of them don't seem to work

1. sh script: "chmod +x ./gradlew;./gradlew test"
2. sh "chmod +x gradle"
   sh "gradle test"

i have also added:
tools {
gradle "gradle-current"
}

for the gradle plugin

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, posting it here if anyone else need it. I had to change the permission for my .sh files and then push them to my repository.
The steps:

```
C:\FilePath>git ls-files --stage
100644 e77de56cc2d1d6434b8b29ae775ik6s2e48c9604 0       foo.sh
```

The mode is 0644 (not executable). we need to change it to 0755 to make it executable

```
C:\FilePath>git update-index --chmod=+x foo.sh

C:\FilePath>git ls-files --stage
100755 e77de56cc2d1d6434b8b29ae775ik6s2e48c9604 0       foo.sh
```

Now the file is mode 0755 (executable).

```
C:\Temp\TestRepo>git commit -m "Executable!"
[master (root-commit) 1f7a57a] Executable!
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 foo.sh
```

Now we have a single commit with a single executable file.